# Two Java applications can't open JxBrowser at the same time

Tags: jxbrowser

I'm using JxBrowser version 6.2.

When I try to open two instances of this application and the JxBrowser is opened in one of them the other is totally hanging, and continues processing.

How can I open two instances of Jxbrowser from two different applications simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser 6 didn't handle a case when it's initialized from multiple Java processes simultaneously. We added such possibility in JxBrowser 7. For example, in 7.24 we [fixed](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/release-notes/2022/v7-24.html#quality-enhancements) that latest "Synchronize the concurrent Chromium binaries extraction between multiple JVMs" issue regarding such use case. I recommend that you take a look at 7.24 or higher.